# In Android, what is this feature called?

Tags: android

When your shown a partial list of information separated by a horizontal bar and click on a piece and your shown more for example

---

Name:

Age:

---

Name:

Age:

---

then you click on one and your shown more information

---

Name:

Age:

Height:

Weight:

---

Comment: Expandable list view my friend. To me it feels like no mans zone trying to find out how to use something without the name xD

Answer (score 1):

It is expandable list BTW your English is fantastic